# Facing issue while creating VSTS Private agent

Tags: azure-devops

I could able to download the private agent and tried to configure the agent with my laptop/local machine.At particular step its failing with the below error:

**Error:**

Loading RSA key parameters from file C:\vsts-agent-win-x64-2.127.0.credentials_rsaparams [2018-02-02 11:31:54Z WARN VisualStudioServices] Attempt 1 of POST request to projname.vssps.visualstudio.com/_apis/oauth2/token failed (WinHttp Error: ERROR_WINHTTP_TIMEOUT). The operation will be retried in 10.89 seconds

Its failing After the steps like server URL,PAT,agent pool name.Its saying connecting to server and then at testing agent connection step its taking some time and then cmd abruptly closing itself.So please do the needful.I have all the logs its creating under C:\vsts-agent-win-x64-2.127.0_diag folder.

Comment: Did you take more than 5 minutes for config your agent? What if you immediately input the agent pool after the console asks?

Comment: @ Marina Liu - MSFT, Yes,Its taking more than 5 minutes.After inputting he agent pool,I am getting the console messages scanning for tool capabilities,connecting to the server,successfully added the agent.After this testing agent connection point its taking more than 5 minutes and console is closing abruptly.So please help me what can I do here?

Comment: @PRAVEEN it appears your agent doesn't have access to the internet.  What have you done to ensure it does, and can successfully connection to visualstudio.com?

Comment: @PRAVEEN What if you execute `set VSTS_HTTP_TIMEOUT=600` in powershell (timeout after 10 min) if you can using Windows OS, then close the agent config window, and reopen powershell window as Administrator to config your private agent? Besides, you can check connection to VSTS, you can clone a git repo from VSTS to check the connection.

Comment: @ raterus,yes,I do have internet connection and console saying that the connection is established and I can see the agent pool name in VSTS.The console is not coming to online in VSTS(Showing offline')because of its testing the connection establishment step  is not properly done and console is closing abruptly at this particular step while configuring the agent from command line.

Comment: @Marina Liu - MSFT, I could able to install the private agent and I can see in VSTS agent pools and it came online but its not showing under Agent queues.Whenever I try to build it should ask the agent name and branch right there its not showing this particular agent name which I installed in VSTS.Please help me out how to pull out under the agent queue section in VSTS.

Comment: @Marina Liu - MSFT, Now,I can able to see the created agent in the agent queue section...But when I try to trigger the build I am getting the error like No registered agents found in the selected queue with the following capabilities: maven. Use a different queue.Please help me out what can I do? I have currently mapped the private agent with my personal laptop so sonar can run from private agent now but to run how to avoid this issue as its asking for the capabilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For timeout error when configuring a private agent, you can set the variable `VSTS_HTTP_TIMEOUT` bigger than it’s default value, such as `set VSTS_HTTP_TIMEOUT=600`.

For the new configured agent doesn’t show under agent queues, you can add it manually. Or when you creating a agent pool, make sure **Auto-provision Queues in all Projects** option is select, so the agent pool will auto showed under all projects agent queues.

[image]

For the error "No registered agents found in the selected queue with the following capabilities: maven. Use a different queue" when queuing a build by the agent, you should make sure maven is installed on the agent machine, and also check if maven is added under the agent capabilites. If maven is not added in the agent capabilities, you can add it manually by providing the name and the path for maven similar as below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have installed maven and I can see its path and M@_HOME reflected under the Private agent capabilities.But still its asking for mvn capability.Please help me here.

Comment: Can you add the screen shot for your private agent capabilities?

Comment: @ Marina Liu - MSFT,I set the maven variable path to M2_HOME that's why Its not taking.Now as you said I have put Mavan to maven home directory now its not throwing error.thanks a lot for your help.But now if I want to run batch command or maven pom.xml where should I keep all these files in my machine?

Comment: You can add three variables `M2_HOME`, `maven` and `MAVEN_HOME`  with the same value (path to the maven you installed).

Comment: @ Marina Liu - MSFT,In VSTS if I want to run sonar for particular project where should I configure in VSTS build task?Please help me here.Now my build is running but want to run sonar on this.

Comment: @ Marina Liu - MSFT,Now,I found the option in VSTS build in maven task .The option is Run sonarcube analysis but if I trigger the build getting the error like ::::Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/3.0.0/maven-clean-plugin-3.0.0.pom
Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:3.0.0: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:3.0.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:3.0.

Comment: Since the question now is far away from what you asked originalyl, you can post your current problem in a new post. And since the answer has already solved what you asked before, you can mark the answer. And it will also benefit other members to read the Q&A clearly.